# How to connect with x2go to remote desktop via public ip?

Tags: remote-desktop, ip, remote-access, hot-spot, x2go

I have two laptops. Using x2go I succeeded at connection from one to another and vice versa via local IP, e.g. in the field `Host` i typed `192.168.0.101` for first and `192.168.0.102` for second.

Now, I'm trying to connect those two laptops via public IP, by `public IP` I mean output of command `curl ifconfig.me`. From first laptop I get output of this command and put it in the field `Host` of the second laptop, no else settings were changed, but after trying to connect x2go gets me output of error `Cannot connect to {IP}:22. Timeout connectiong to {IP}`

In the field host I entered `username@{IP}`

First laptop IP has given by Wi-Fi router, second laptop has IP from hotspot of my smartphone, so they have different `IP` and not connected to local network, and, I assume, behave like machines that located remotely without any idea of each other. What I'm missing? I would appreciate any help, because now I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

X2go works by sending data over an SSH connection. Port 22 is the SSH port. Your error message says that port 22 is not available on the public IP. To make it work you need to reconfigure the Wifi router to forward the public port 22 to port 22 on the laptop's LAN address (`192.168.0.101`).

Please ensure that anything that receives traffic to port 22 via a public IP is properly secured, because botnets all over the Internet will quickly find that port and start attacking. It is considered good practice to set `PasswordAuthentication no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and only use cryptographic key pairs for authentication.